What is the Salesforce Event Manager?
In Salesforce setup I just found the "Event Manager". What does it do and why does it only have one event? I cannot seem to find any documentation regarding this. Whenever I googled it I only end up with platform events.


This is covered in the documentation and requires a separate license for Salesforce Shield Event Monitoring

Important Viewing Real-Time Event Monitoring events requires Salesforce Shield or Salesforce Event Monitoring add-on subscriptions.
You don’t need this add-on to view streaming logout events.


No wonder I couldn't find it. I just ended up with platform events and even when reading this it did not really explain what it's for (e.g. why it exists) and why there's only one event that you can use without an additional subscription. With the example, I can at least understand the use case a little better so thanks for this link.

Salesforce Event Manager is a tool within Salesforce that helps you manage and monitor events in real-time. It allows you to track standard events, store event data for auditing or reporting purposes, and create transaction security policies using tools like Condition Builder or Apex code
